# How to check if the DSC (USB token) is attached while signing the document?

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, signing, digital-certificate

I am digitally signing the xml document. Here is my code:

```
private void mbSign_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
            CadesSignature cs = new CadesSignature(FStrDSCSNo);
                            cs.DigitalSignatureCertificate = DigitalCertificate.LoadCertificate(false, string.Empty, "Select Certificate", "Select the certificate for digital signature");
                            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaEncryptor = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cs.DigitalSignatureCertificate.PrivateKey;

        L_ADSC_ValidTo = cs.DigitalSignatureCertificate.NotAfter.ToShortDateString();

        if (DateTime.Now <= DateTime.ParseExact(L_ADSC_ValidTo, "dd/MM/yyyy", null))
                        {
                            FObjLog.WriteToLog("Valid DSC");
                            L_ADSC_CertStatus = "A";
                            // Sign the XML document.
                            //DataTable dt_SignXMlAndSignaute = new DataTable();
                            SignXml(rsaEncryptor);
                        }
}

catch (CryptographicException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid DSC Selection.Please Choose Correct DSC");
                FObjLog.WriteToLog("Invalid DSC Selection.Please Choose Correct DSC");
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Attach DSC");
                FObjLog.WriteToLog("Please Attach DSC");
            }

  }
public void SignXml(RSA Key)
        {
XmlDocument LXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
            if (File.Exists(LXMLPath))
            {
                LXMLDoc.Load(LXMLPath);
            }
                if (LXMLDoc == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("LXMLDoc");
                if (Key == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Key");

                // Create a SignedXml object.
                SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(LXMLDoc);

                // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
                signedXml.SigningKey = Key;

                // Create a reference to be signed.
                Reference reference = new Reference();
                //reference.Uri = txtfilepath.Text;
                reference.Uri = "";

                // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
                XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
                reference.AddTransform(env); // calculating Digest value

                // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
                signedXml.AddReference(reference);

                // Add an RSAKeyValue KeyInfo (optional; helps recipient find key to validate).
                KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
                keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)Key));
                signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

                signedXml.ComputeSignature();

                string FullSignatureValue = "";
                string SignatureValue = "";
                XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
                FullSignatureValue = xmlDigitalSignature.InnerText;
                string[] Sign = FullSignatureValue.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);


                SignatureValue = Sign[1].ToString();

                signedXml = new SignedXml(LXMLDoc);
LXMLDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(LXMLDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
}
```

Here i am able to sign the document but i am unable to check if the USB token is attached while signing. Here what is happening is even if the USB token is not attached the certificate will pop up for the selection because the certificate is available locally. When you remove all the certificates from Internet Explorer and try to sign with USB token not attached then it is asking to attach DSC card(USB token). I want to sign the document only when the DSC (USB Token) is attached. How do i ensure that the USB is attached while signing?

Answer (score 0):

The CryptoAPI and CNG system interfaces (and .NET classes that use those interfaces) offer high-level abstractions that don't let you check the hardware. If you use PKCS#11 interface, then you might be able to achieve what you want. However, PKCS#11 has its drawbacks too.

Answer (score 0):

CryptoAPI and CNG don't expose card status information, for that you want WINSCARD. Specifically you want to call SCARDGetStatusChange.

```
private void WaitChangeStatus(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!e.Cancel)
        {
            SmartCardErrorCode result;

            // Obtain a lock when we use the context pointer, which may be modified in the Dispose() method.
            lock (this)
            {
                if (!this.HasContext)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // This thread will be executed every 1000ms. 
                // The thread also blocks for 1000ms, meaning 
                // that the application may keep on running for 
                // one extra second after the user has closed the Main Form.
                result = (SmartCardErrorCode)UnsafeNativeMethods.GetStatusChange(this.context, 1000, this.states, (uint)this.states.Length);
            }

            if ((result == SmartCardErrorCode.Timeout))
            {
                // Time out has passed, but there is no new info. Just go on with the loop
                continue;
            }
            else if (result != SmartCardErrorCode.Succeeed)
            {
                // TODO OnExceptionRaised
                continue;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= this.states.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                // Check if the state changed from the last time.
                if ((this.states[i].EventState & CardState.Changed) == CardState.Changed)
                {
                    // Check what changed.
                    SmartCardState state = SmartCardState.None;
                    if ((this.states[i].EventState & CardState.Present) == CardState.Present
                        && (this.states[i].CurrentState & CardState.Present) != CardState.Present)
                    {
                        // The card was inserted.                            
                        state = SmartCardState.Inserted;
                    }
                    else if ((this.states[i].EventState & CardState.Empty) == CardState.Empty
                        && (this.states[i].CurrentState & CardState.Empty) != CardState.Empty)
                    {
                        // The card was ejected.
                        state = SmartCardState.Ejected;
                    }
                    if (state != SmartCardState.None && this.states[i].CurrentState != CardState.Unaware)
                    {
                        SmartCardEventArgs args = new SmartCardEventArgs();
                        args.Manager = this;

                        switch(state)
                        {
                            case SmartCardState.Inserted:
                            {
                                // Checa o ATR para monitorar apenas DESFire EV1
                                if (OnCardInserted != null)
                                {
                                    // Obtém o ATR
                                    byte[] atr = this.GetAtr(this.states[i].ATRBytes, this.states[i].ATRLength);

                                    // Cria SmartCard object and associa ao EventArgs
                                    SmartCard card = new SmartCard(atr);
                                    args.Card = card;

                                    // Dispara Evento
                                    OnCardInserted(this, args);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            case SmartCardState.Ejected:
                            {
                                if (OnCardRemoved != null)
                                {
                                    OnCardRemoved(this, args);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            default:
                            {
                                // TODO Log

                                // Null to force Garbage Collection
                                args = null; 

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Update the current state for the next time they are checked.
                    this.states[i].CurrentState = this.states[i].EventState;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```